# Insert HTML dynamically based on CSS class with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

With the use of Javascript I want to display different HTML content based on the value of a class of an HTML element which is existing on the page. eg:

```
<body class="de">
```

display:

```
<div id="de">some html</div>
```

If the body element has another class value, eg `class="en"` it should display

```
<div id="en">some other html</div>
```

I have already played around with hasClass function and an if statement. But it did not work for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Under what circumstances does your `<body>` have different class names?

Comment: Please show a complete example of the HTML, and your "hasClass function and an if statement." It's impossible to tell what's wrong with your code without seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about ?

```
<body class="en">
<script>
if($('body').hasClass('de')) {
  $('body').html('<div id="de">some html</div>');
}
else if($('body').hasClass('en')) {
  $('body').html('<div id="en">some other html</div>');
}
else if($('body').hasClass('es')) {
  $('body').html('<div id="es">another html</div>');
}
else {
  ...
}
</script>
```

Dynamic :

```
var bodyClass = $('body').attr("class");
var bodyValue = $('#' + bodyClass).html();
$('body').html(bodyValue);
```

But you should verify that body has a class and that an element with an identical id exist in your document.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I am working with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="lang-de some other">

<h1>&Uuml;berschrift 1</h1>
<div id="lang"></div>

<script>
var bodyClass = $('body').attr("class").substr(0,7);
var bodyValue = $('#' + bodyClass).html();
$('body').html(bodyValue);
    if($('body').hasClass('lang-de')) {
        document.getElementById("lang"); { 
            $('#lang').html('<div id="de">some html</div>');}
    }
        else if ($('body').hasClass('lang-en')) {
        document.getElementById("lang"); { 
            $('#lang').html('<div id="en">some other html</div>');}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery :

```
$('.de').html('<div id="de">some html</div>');
```

If you have different tags to fulfil with different html content use a generic class + a specific one (eg : class="dynamic de") and loop all elements with "dynamic" class and use hasClass in a if/elseif (or better a switch/case) to target them separatly.

Btw, AngularJs has "directives" that handle perfectly that kind of need ;)

Comment: Thanks! I do not want to add AngularJS to this code since it is just a short one. I took your input, see my code below

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="lang-de some other">

<h1>&Uuml;berschrift 1</h1>
<div id="lang-de"></div>
<div id="lang-en"></div>

<script>
var bodyClass = $('body').attr("class").substr(0,7);
$('div#lang-*').hide();
$('#' + bodyClass).show();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**What about?**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body.lang-en #en{display:block;}
  body.lang-de #de{display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body class="lang-en">
  <div id="en" hidden>some text</div>
  <div id="de" hidden>some other text</div>

  <hr>
  <button onclick="toggle()"></button>
</body>

<script>
 function toggle(){
   var lang=['lang-en','lang-de'];
   var i=lang.indexOf(document.body.className);
   document.body.className=(i+1 == lang.length ? 0 :i+1);
 }
</script>
</html>
```

---

OR

with jQuery

```
$('#en,#de,#jp').hide();
$('#'+$('body').attr('class').replace('lang-','')).show();
```

---